# "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" with LuaLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, luatex

I'm trying to compile a 3D surface made by 10000 data points with tickzpicture. However, when I compile the `.tex` file with `lualatex`

```
lualatex --shell-escape myfile.tex
```

I receive the following error:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfgSegmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The script I'm using inside my `.tex` file looks like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
 width=5.33027777777778in,
 height=4.26422222222222in,
 area legend,
 view={-37.5}{30},
 scale only axis,
 xmin=-5, xmax=5,
 xtick={\empty},
 ymin=-1, ymax=7,
 ytick={\empty},
 every outer z axis line/.append style={white},
 every z tick label/.append style={font=\color{white}},
 zmin=-0.458, zmax=5.285,
 ztick={\empty},
 axis x line*=bottom,
 axis y line*=left,
 axis z line*=left]

 \addplot3[%
  surf,
  shader=faceted interp,
  colormap/jet,
  mesh/rows=100]
  table[row sep=crcr,header=false] {
  -5 -1 -0.0254428632617659\\
  -5 -0.919191919191919 -0.0254428632617659\\
  -5 -0.838383838383838 -0.0254428632617659\\
  -5 -0.757575757575758 -0.0254428632617659\\
  -5 -0.676767676767677 -0.0254428632617659\\
  -5 -0.595959595959596 -0.0254428632617659\\
  ............
  ............
  5 6.67676767676768 -0.0254428632617659\\
  5 6.75757575757576 -0.0254428632617659\\
  5 6.83838383838384 -0.0254428632617659\\
  5 6.91919191919192 -0.0254428632617659\\
  5 7 -0.0254428632617659};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Do you know how to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Try to compile a Hello-World-document and `\usepackage{epstopdf}`, because based on your Segfault output snippet `lualatex` crashed while loading this package.

Comment: Hi Henri: I've tried to do a simple Hello-World document with \usepackage{epstopdf} and compiled it with lualatex and everything works.

Comment: @MarcelloM Have you tried running it inside [`gdb`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)? Also do `ldd` on the `lualatex`-binary to check if all symbols are referenced.

Comment: I didn't. But I've been able to solve my problem by updating my pgfplots package to version 1.9. Thank you anyway

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is was caused by an outdated version of `pgfplots` could be solved with a package update.

Comment: Note that `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` should **never** happen unless there is a bug in LuaTeX or a C module it has loaded.